# Присваивание значений url в input и редирект на присвоенный url

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Подскажите как сделать чтобы при выборе марки из таблицы бд присваивалось значение url из этой же таблицы этой марки в input(при нажатии на input должен происходить редирект по этому url)
делал так, не получилось:

```
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                            $('#idcat').change(function(){
                                var val = $(this).val();
                                $('#idcat2').html('');
                                $.ajax({
                                type: 'POST',
                                url: 'templates/megawebshop/html/com_virtuemart/category/show.php',
                                data: {'model': val, 'url': val},
                                success: function(data) {
                                    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                                    obj.forEach(function(item) {
                                        $('#idcat2').append($("<option></option>").attr("value",item).text(item)); 
                                    })
                                }
                                });
                            });
                             $('#idcat2').change(function(){
                                var val = $(this).val();
                                $('#redirect').attr("value", $url)
                            });
                    </script>
                    <input id="redirect" type="submit" name="submit"    value="Кнопка" />

      // файл show.php 

      $MODEL = $_POST['model'];
      $URL = $_POST['url'];


    if (isset($MODEL) && !empty($MODEL)) {

    $query = "SELECT model FROM filtr_db WHERE marka='$MODEL'";
    $DB = mysql_query($query);
    //  Обработаем
    $JSON = array();
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($DB)) {
     $JSON[] = $row['model'];
   }

    //  Выводим
    echo json_encode($JSON);
    } else {
      echo '[]';
      };

   if (isset($URL) && !empty($URL)) {
   $query = "SELECT url FROM filtr_db WHERE model='$URL'";
   $DB = mysql_query($query);
   $url = array();
   while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($DB))
            {
            $url = $row['url']; 

            }
  }
```

Comment: Если вам по нажатию на input нужен редирект, возможно вам и input не к чему? Возможно лучше сформировать ссылку `<a href='asdasd'></a>`. Если вы используете бутстрап или что то ан подобие, то вы можете присвоить ему класс инпута (например `btn btn-success`) и ссылка будет выглядить как кнопка. Сформировать саму ссылку в коде поможет вам `jquery` метод `append`. Нажать на нее в коде - тот же `jquery`: просто выбираете по селектору вашу кнопку и жмакаете на нее `$("#myid").click()`  и ссылка откроется

Comment: Нужно чтобы редирект происходил на значение из бд, не обязательно чтобы это был инпут, можно и ссылкой оформить как кнопку, проблемма в другом...Алгоритм действий такой, Нажимаем выбрать марку=>Подгружаются значения из БД(модели выбранной марки)=>После выбора модели нажимаем кнопку/ссылку подобрать=>Редирект на url который указан в БД, первые 2 пункта выполняются,т.е. мы выбрали марку и модель,теперь нужно нажать подобрать,и вот на этом этапе и проблема...У каждой модели свой уникальный url

Comment: кнопка `подобрать ссылку` вытягивает url из таблицы? с той же что и модели? я имею в виду для каждой модели она (кнопка) должна тянуть из бд свою ссылку?

Comment: Верно !Архитектура таблицы:  id|marka|model|url

Comment: я так пониаю модель выбирается в `<select> html`. 1) [определить выбранную модель](http://w3.org.ua/js/rabota-s-elementom-select-v-js/) 2) послать запрос на бэкенд, в запросе выборкой (зная модель) вытянуть url 3) Вернуть в `success` запроса `url` 4) там же построить на основе вытянутого `url` новый тег

Comment: А можете мой код подредактировать который я приложил выше, а то не могу понять как это реализовать, там надо как я понял в ajax добавить код который будет вытягивать url

Comment: все у вас нормально. `$('#idcat2').change(function(){}` сюда вставьте еще один ajax запрос, и вытяньте url и по аналогии первому вставьте url

Comment: $('#idcat2').change(function(){
                  var val = $(this).val();
                  $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  url: 'templates/megawebshop/html/com_virtuemart/category/show.php',
                  data: {'url': val},
                  success: function(data) {
                      var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                      obj.forEach(function(item) {
                         $('#idcat2').append($("<option></option>").attr("value",item).text(item)); 
                   })
                }
                });
            }); Так?

Comment: ссылки тоже в select вставлять? я думал вы одну выберете

Comment: Нет ссылки не вставлять

Comment: а какой url вы собрались в ajax-е передовать? Вам надо передать в php код выбранную модель в select. А url вы получите в ответ

Comment: url из бд, я может что то не правильно понимаю но нужно сделать так чтобы input присваивал значение url из таблицы выбранной модели а потом при нажатии делал редирект по этому полученному значению

Comment: Url у вас уже есть на странице, или его нужно вытянуть из бд сначала?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80797/discussion-between---and-ilyaaa521).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант с `PDO` вам не понравился? ну да ладно,

```
$hostname = "localhost"; 
$username = "root"; 
$password = ""; 
$dbName = ""; 


mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die ("Не могу создать соединение");
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8') or header('Location: Error');

mysql_select_db($dbName) or die (mysql_error());


 $MODEL = $_POST['model'];


if (isset($MODEL) && !empty($MODEL)) {
    $query = "SELECT model, url FROM filtr_db WHERE marka='$MODEL'";
    $DB = mysql_query($query);
    $JSON = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($DB)) {
        $JSON[$row['model']] = $row['url'];
    }

    echo json_encode($JSON);
} else {
    echo '[]';
}
```

Сверху мы в запрос добавили `url` и переделали формирование массива, далее меняем формирование второго списка:

```
success: function(data) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
    $.each(obj, function( index, value ) {
      $('#idcat2').append($("<option></option>").attr("value",index).text(value));
    });
}
```

Далее при выборе:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $('#idcat2').change(function(){
        var val = $(this).val();
        window.location.href = val;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо, я вчера сам помозговал и сделал по другому, сделал кнопку подобрать ссылкой заключлил в теги <а> далее прописал что то типо  $('#idcat2').change(function(){
        var val = $(this).val(); ниже код аякс, с url: show2.php, в show2.php прописал код по аналогии как и в show.php который возвращал модели  
       $("#redirect").attr( "href" val )   // Незнаю на сколько такой вариант правильный, но он рабочий